# How to create a thread of a pointer to a function C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I know that in order to create a thread of a method on an Object I can do it in this way:

```
#include <thread> 
using namespace std;

class Character
{
public:
    void myFunction(int a){ /* */ }

    void startThreadMyFunction(int a){
      thread Mf1(&Character::myFunction, this, a);
    }
};
```

Also I know that in order to have a pointer to a function in my class I can do it in this way:

```
#include <thread>  
using namespace std;

class Character
{
private:
    void (*FMoveForward)(int);// Pointer to a function.
public:
    void setCommands(void(mf)(int delay)){//This function sets the pointer.
      FMoveForward = mf;
    }
    void MoveForward(int delay){
      FMoveForward(delay);// Here a call my function with my pointer to function.
    }
};
```

My problem is that all the time when I try to use both of these things together the Visual Studio 13 compiler always complain about the sintaxe.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Character
{
private:
    void (*FMoveForward)(int);
public:
    void setCommands(void(mf)(int delay)){
      FMoveForward = mf;
    }
    void MoveForward(int delay){
      thread Mf1(&Character::FMoveForward , this, delay);// The VS 13 Complain because the sintaxe os this line.
    }

};
```

Does anyone knows how to solve it? TY in advanced...

Comment: Can you be more specific about the compiler error?

Comment: You are passing `this` as first parameter for function on thread creation, but FMoveFoward is just a pointer to a function, not to a method. Try this: `thread Mf1(FMoveForward , delay)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that pointers to **member** functions are not pointers to **free** functions.
`std::thread` can use both, but you need to be consistent.

In your first example, you have a pointer to a member function. OK.

In your second example, you have a pointer to a free function. Also OK.

In your third example, `FMoveForward` is a pointer to a free function. `&Character::FMoveForward` is a pointer to a pointer. That's not going to work.

If you want to store `&Character::myFunction`, you would need a `void (Character::*FMoveForward)(int);` member. That's a pointer to a member function

Answer (score 0):

This

```
thread Mf1(&Character::FMoveForward ,0 this, delay);// The VS 13 Complain because the sintaxe os this line.
```

happens to have a syntax error: `0 this`

Comment: Sorry. That 0 was my fault. My code do not has that. Even without that 0 the VS13 complain.

Comment: OK. See the comment by alvmed